# Multiple Input fields of file type on a single view

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, file-upload

im developing an application where i need to provide two upload file options one for the image and one is for video, i have this code [Ref](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/ABackToBasicsCaseStudyImplementingHTTPFileUploadWithASPNETMVCIncludingTestsAndMocks.aspx)

```
foreach (string file in Request.Files)
{
   HttpPostedFile hpf = Request.Files[file] as HttpPostedFile;
   if (hpf.ContentLength == 0)
      continue;
   string savedFileName = Path.Combine(
      AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory, 
      Path.GetFileName(hpf.FileName));
   hpf.SaveAs(savedFileName);
}
```

and in the view

```
<input type="file" id="fileUpload1" name="fileUpload1" size="23" class="image" /> 
<input type="file" id="fileUpload2" name="fileUpload2" size="23" class="video" />
```

it works fine the files get uploaded but the problem is how can i determine which file comes from which input type so to differentiate between the image and the video because i have to then assign separate unique names to them and save to the database.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could identify the image using the content type of the [HttpPostedFileBase](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httppostedfilebase.aspx)

```
if (file.ContentType.Contains("image"))
{
    var isImage = true;
}
```

If you just have the one image you are sorted, you could also check for your video content type for validation.  If you had two images we'd probably have to think of something else.

Comment: nope i have only one image and one video, this solution looks fine ... tnx

Answer (score 2):

A probably better way would be to identify the files by key.

`Request.Files["fileUpload1"]` should return the image

and

`Request.Files["fileUpload2"]` should return the video

And FYI, `Request.Files.AllKeys` has all the keys for all the files uploaded and they should match to whatever names you gave to the `<input type="file"...` elements.